# Testing API with Swagger/OAS

Tags: testing, swagger, openapi

I've spent some time documenting an API with Swagger/OAS 3. I want to validate our current API conforms with the OAS 3 document. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Your schema and examples defined in it could be used to generate and execute test cases with tools like [Schemathesis](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis).

It uses both examples and schemas and doesn't require configuration by default. It utilizes property-based testing to generate data and verifies properties defined in the tested schema - response codes, schemas, and headers. It also treats any 5xx responses as errors and will report it.

The simplest way to run it:

```
schemathesis run -c all http://my.server.com/openapi.json
```

This command will read the schema, generate tests, execute them against that server, run all built-in checks, and report all found problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your **OpenAPI Specifications** as "[**Contract Tests**](https://specmatic.in/#contract-as-test)" with [**Specmatic**](https://specmatic.in/) ([video demo](https://youtu.be/U5Agz-mvYIU?t=34)).

Please see [documentation](https://specmatic.in/getting_started.html#provider-side---contract-as-a-test) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`swagger-cli`](https://github.com/James-Messinger/swagger-cli) to validate your spec.

```
swagger-cli validate Test.yaml
```

Comment: I'm not looking to validate the spec, I'm looking to check the API response validates against the spec. I.e. is what the API sending back what we expect it to